# Qt5 examples package on Debian

Tags: c++, qt, debian, package

How can I separately get the package with examples for Qt5 on Debian Jessie? I have QtCreator with Qt5 and can develop Qt apps, however I do not have the examples. Synaptic Package Manager comes up with too many hits when I search Qt. I think the closes thing to what I want is `qtbase5-examples`, but I'm not 100% sure if this is what I have to download.

Answer (score 8):

These files are provided by `qtbase5-examples`, this is correct. However, the files are not installed in obvious path and it depends on the architecture:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/ [amd64]
>
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/ [i386]

[More info about paths](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=chip%2Fview.cpp&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)

These files are correct qt5 example code from the [Qt Examples List](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/all-examples.html).

Comment: For some reason, you also need `qtbase5-doc-html` package for the examples to show up automatically in Examples section of Qt Creator (with Stretch, current Debian stable).

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need it to be from the debian repository.
I would recommend getting the examples form the download page.
That has worked better for me.
Also if you begin to develop on another system, other linuxes or windows etc,
then you don't have to go and search for right packages.
If you use the installers, you can get all samples, that is not necessarily true when using a distro package.

http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.zip

Git repositories to get the code updated and you can check out the release you want.
http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/

All downloads (OpenSource) page:
http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2

Comment: Downvote: The question was explicitly about a Debian package.